# How to check isAccessible() for a dynamic list of field names?

Tags: apex, security-review

I have a list of field names in an array:

```
String desiredFieldList; //'AccountId, Id, FirstName ... 'etc
String originObjectName; //'Contact', or 'Opportunity' etc

queryString = 'SELECT ' + desiredFieldList + ' FROM ' + searchObjectName + ' WHERE Id=:searchObjectId';
            List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query(queryString);
```

But for security review I need to check isAccessible() for each one of those fields for the given object. Normally I can do this using something like (Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Email.isAccessible()) {} but in this case, since the list is dynamic, I'm not sure how to go about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a single field as a string, if you know the `sObjectType` as a string also, you can do:

```
public static Boolean isAccessible(String sObjectType, String fieldName)
{
    SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = schemaType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
    return fieldDescribe.isAccessible();
}
```

If you have them as a comma delimited list, you need to do a bit of processing.

```
public static List<SObject> query(String sObjectType, String commaDelimitedFields)
{
    SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = schemaType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    List<String> fields = new List<String>();
    for (String field : commaDelimitedFields.split(','))
        if (fields.get(field).getDescribe().isAccessible())
            fields.add(field.trim());
    String soql = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' FROM ' + sObjectType;
    return Database.query(soql);
}
```

Comment: Took the words right out of my textarea box.

Comment: Haha! Great minds. :P

Comment: Thank you! That looks like just the ticket. I didn't know about .get(sObjectType) and get(field).getDescribe()

Comment: Right, notice that those are just maps, the former being a `Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>`, and the latter being a `Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>`. The `Schema.` bit is optional most of the time (unless you have a naming collision).

Comment: Actually - there is a small issue: Invalid type: DescribeSObject

Comment: That doesn't seem quite right either. Is it Schema.SObjectType? The error I'm seeing now is  Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectType to Schema.DescribeSObjectResult

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks again. BTW I have a bounty open for another question related to Salesforce Oauth if you're looking for some more points!

Comment: The answer is correct. Also, this is how you protect against SOQL injection for field names/table names -- if the user supplies code instead of a field name, your fields.get(name) will be null and you'll get a Null Pointer Error when you dereference it. Please catch this error and abort the operation. escapeSingleQuotes only protects you from breaking out of a quoted WHERE or LIKE clause -- the getDescribe is how you sanitize object names/field names in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @RobertSussland I would actually proactively check if the field is in the map over catching a NPE. Just personal preference, not sure if one is better than the other.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, that would be better as long as you remember to halt execution if *any* of the fields aren't in the map. Don't try to fix the query but reject it entirely, which is what an exception does for you. Of course knowing which field is useful for error reporting.

Comment: @AdrianLarson and others, is the above solution able to pass the security review for Salesforce appExchange? we are running the same problem so want to confirm if this does help. thanks